# How do I clean up the temp files created by SharpZipLib

Tags: file, sharpziplib, temp

When I create a zip file using SharpZipLib I end up with .tmp files litering my hard drive.  It occurs when I add files to an archive.

I'm not too concerned that it's happening, but I'd like to be able to get the file name so that I can remove the files once the archive is completed.  How do I get the name of the .tmp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm switching to a different library.

Comment: what choice you take? (I have to switch too)

Comment: I went with DotNetZip ( http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/27890 )

They just released an updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the zip file you are creating?  I use SharpZipLib for several apps and the .tmp file is always cleaned up automatically by the process once the newly generated zip file is closed and released by the process in every one of my apps.

Comment: Yep.  I'm closing the archive.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it isn't cleaning up after itself then.  As I say, it does on the version I am using by itself.